# Why isn't Typescript showing an error when using an implicit Any?

Tags: typescript, type-inference, tsconfig

In my tsconfig.json I have set `"noImplicitAny": true`. However the following code doesn't produce an error:

```
let x;
x = 5;
x = "a";
x = null;
console.log(x);
```

Isn't `x` implicitly set to `any` here (as opposed to explicitly, where I would write `let x: Any;`)?

I understand that, because of the different assignments, the compiler can infer `Any` at compile time here, but I thought the option `"noImplicitAny": true` is used to prevent this inference.

Is there some other compiler option to show an error in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript may infer a variable to be a subtype of its actual type depending on context:

```
let a: number | number[] = 0;
if (!Array.isArray(a)) a = [a];
void a;
//   ^?
// let a: number[] | (number & any[])

a = 123;
void a;
//   ^?
// let a: number

if (a === 999) {
    void a;
    //   ^?
    // let a: 999
}

function f() {
    // doesn't work in functions:
    void a;
    //   ^?
    // let a: number | number[]
}
```

If you define variable type as `unknown` subtyping will stop working for assignements.
If you define variable type as `any` subtyping will stop working for everywhere.
If you won't write the type it'll be taken from the value you assigned.

If you however don't define variable type at all, it'll be a subtypeable `any`

Answer (score 1):

Typescript postprocesses when you have an unassigned let variable in your code and it accepts last assignment's type as your variable's type (dont ask me why)

That's why we generally use 'const' keyword instead of 'let'.

```
let x; // here its any
x = 5; // here its number
const num = x; // hover on num to see its type
x = "a"; // here its string
const str = x; // hover on str to see its type

str = 123; // that's not allowed
x = 123; // but this is

console.log(x); // here its number again
```